# Field names in announcement list in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, client-object-model, column, addfieldasxml

I am trying to add fields to an announcement list. 
I have successfully added various fields with single-word names:

```
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='User' DisplayName='CreatedBy'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='DateTime' DisplayName='DateCreated'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);    
announcementy.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo1 = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem1 = announcementy.AddItem(itemCreateInfo1);
oListItem1["Title"] = "Item no " + i.ToString() + " with body";
oListItem1["CreatedBy"] = context.Web.CurrentUser;
oListItem1["DateCreated"] = DateTime.Now;
oListItem1.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

However when I change DateCreated into Date Created it gives me the following errors, which is weird considering that it is a DisplayName/Title:

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields.

and

> Column 'Date Created' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.   /sites/TeamsiteWithLists/Announcements list

I found that it may be [a bug](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/420147) and tried to use a workaround with first creating single-word names and then renaming them, but Sharepoint didn't react/execute/like it and users still see "CreatedBy" instead of "Created By":

```
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='User' DisplayName='CreatedBy'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='DateTime' DisplayName='DateCreated'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
announcementy.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("CreatedBy").Title = "Created By";
announcementy.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("DateCreated").Title = "Date Created";
announcementy.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Running .Title="" under separate ExecuteQuery or after Sleep() didn't change anything. Manual change is not an option. How can I set it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of using [AddFieldAsXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457586(v=office.15).aspx) you need to provide the field's internal and staticname

```
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='User' DisplayName='Created By' StaticName='CreatedBy' Name='CreatedBy'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
announcementy.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='DateTime' DisplayName='Date Created' StaticName='DateCreated' Name='DateCreated'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
```

An interesting article on this topic http://blog.martinhey.de/en/post/2012/01/22/AddFieldAsXml-bug-or-feature-that-is-the-question.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting "Column 'CreatiedBy' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."  I changed the name into Creatied so as to make sure it doesn't clash with the default column. It's not an issue of provisioning either - if I try to access the column after it appears in GUI,I get the same error. I'm not getting these issues in a generic list where I create fields with DisplayName only. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the list got created and now you are unable to add/edit data?

Comment: Yes, the columns are added, and the displayNames are showing correctly. I just cannot access them later via internal/static names.

Comment: Open list settings page and click on the column name. Check the URL and make sure the field name in query string is correct.

Comment: It works with oListItem1["Created_x0020_By"] and 
              oListItem1["Date_x0020_Created"].  So despite declaring internal/static names, SPO seems to take a displayname and parse the space :)  Not perfect, but solves my issue.Thanks.

Comment: @grisha nice to hear that.